# Should the Android Files apps be able to see Scoped Storage of other apps?

Tags: android, scoped-storage

So I'm trying to confirm if my scoped storage usage on Android is working correctly.

Note - I'm using Xamarin but hopefully can explain this all fine so its just a general Android question.

I'm saving data to the following location....

```
Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath
```

This produces URLs similar to this...

```
"/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.xxx/files/Documents"
```

I *believe* this is correct based on the documentation (but hey, its Android documentation) here...

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

> Starting in Android 11, apps cannot create their own app-specific
> directory on external storage. To access the directory that the system
> provides for your app, call getExternalFilesDirs()

However, the in built files app on Android can browse and see the file all stored there? Is that...expected? I assumed scoped storage was completely hidden from view? I can go to  Main Storage -> Android -> Data -> com.xxx.xxx -> Files -> Documents and see all my files in 'scoped storage' there?

Note - The phone I'm testing on is only running Android 10 currently but i'm not using requestLegacyExternalStorage and I'm targetting 30.

Comment: You cannot test Android 11 behaviour on an Android 10 device. Take a Android 11 emulator to test.

Comment: Android 10 has scoped storage too though, and I have not set requestLegacyExternalStorage soo should be using scoped storage?

Comment: But, judging by this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific because I use External Storage that makes sense that the inbuilt android files app would have permission to see the files.

I'm just finding it hard to confirm the external storage location i'm using is 100% fine with scoped storage restrictions. I'm assuming it is (as it appears to work in 10 with scoped storage limitations) but its proving a pain to confirm via the android documentation.

Comment: An Android 11 device behaves different as an Android 10 device. And your question is not about scoped storage but about what the Files app will display. So take an Android 11 device/emulator.

Comment: My question is about scoped storage? Its there in the title...